# How to add a matrix section to pipeline to run the pipeline on multiple nodes?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I want to add a matrix section to the following pipeline. I want the pipeline to run on 4 nodes with each node running a different stage that is specified in the for loop (e.g. **one node runs AD, the other runs CD, the other runs DC, and the last runs DISP_A. It then repeats this behavior for the rest of the list until it is done iterating to the end of the list**).

I have looked at the documentation and have not come up with any concrete answers to my question.

```
pipeline 
{
    agent none

    stages
    {
        stage ('Test')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    def test_proj_choices = ['AD', 'CD', 'DC', 'DISP_A', 'DISP_PROC', 'EGI', 'FD', 'FLT', 'FMS_C', 'IFF', 'liblO', 'libNGC', 'libSC', 'MISCMP_MP', 'MISCMP_GP', 'NAV_MGR', 'RADALT', 'SYS', 'SYSIO15', 'SYSIO42', 'SYSRED', 'TACAN', 'VOR_ILS', 'VPA', 'WAAS', 'WCA']
                    for (choice in test_proj_choices) 
                    {
                        stage ("${choice}") 
                        {
                            echo "Running ${choice}"
                            build job: "UH60Job", parameters: [string(name: "TEST_PROJECT", value: choice), string(name: "SCADE_SUITE_TEST_ACTION", value: "all"), string(name: "VIEW_ROOT", value: "myview")] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a good [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix). With this you can structure your matrix and stages

Comment: I am still having issues after looking at the docs. I need the matrix section to work with my specific example but cannot figure out how.

Comment: not with matrix but with groovy logic, I have tried to decorate a similar example like you, take a look and try - If that something you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your expectation can be decorated with Jenkins matrix DSL, as matrix DSL works like a single or multi-dimensional array.

But you can do something similar by writing a small groovy logic.

Below is one small example similar to your expectation:

The expectation of this example will run one task in one Jenkins agent in a distributed fashion.

Meaning it will run this way (Task - agent) `A - will run on- agent1`, `B - will run on- agent2`, `C  -will run on- agent3`, `D - will run on- agent4`, `E - will run on- agent1`, ....

```
node {
    agent=['agent1','agent2','agent3', 'agent4']
    tasks=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L']
    int nodeCount=0
    
    tasks.each {
        node(agent[nodeCount]) {
            stage("build") {
                println "Task - ${it} running on ${agent[nodeCount]}"
            }
        }
        nodeCount=nodeCount+1
        if(nodeCount == agent.size()){
            nodeCount=0
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkins agent no need to be hardcode, by using Jenkins groovy api, you can easily find all the available and active agent from Jenkins, like below.

```
agent=[]
for (a in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
  if(!a.getComputer().isOffline()) {
     agent << a.name
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I apply the code you provided to my example? (I am using the declarative syntax)

Comment: the example I have given is the scripted pipeline . If you need one similar with declarative I might need to EDIT my answer and add the declarative one.
or Just copy the block and put it inside declarative `script {}` DSL